# The process can not access the file 'directory\file' because it is being used by another process in C# File Writer

Tags: c#, streaming, ioexception, notepad

I receive this error when ever I attempt to save on the existing file:

> the process can not access the file because it is being used by another process

It works when a file doesn't exist, but when I attempt to write in it again the error shows up. I'm not accessing or using the file that time.

here is the code:

```
string directory = filepath + "Updates\\" + dir;
if(!Directory.Exists(directory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}
remarks = remarks.Trim();
remarks = remarks.Replace("\r\n","<br>");
remarks = remarks.Replace(",","|");
string file = directory + "\\" +  getIndex(barcode) + ".asdt";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file,true);
writer.WriteLine(username + "," + barcode + "," + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm")+ "," + remarks);
writer.Close();
```

When I checked it the error occurs on the line:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file,true);
```

what could be the cause of this?

Comment: I support Odded's answer, but if you are not sure which program is blocking the file, try to use the program "unlocker"

Comment: The SysInternals' Handle utility is a better bargain.  Although you're likely to find out it is your own program.

Comment: @all - I think it's not appending it to the file rather creating a new file which makes the conflict. how can I avoid recreating a new file. Is it because my statement streamwriter(file,true) is true?

Comment: Your Code is working on my PC, Try to write to another file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is probably not disposing of the file stream properly, keeping the file open.

Use the `using` statement to ensure proper disposal:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file,true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(username + "," + barcode + "," + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm")+ "," + remarks);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: it seems that I just need to revert the bool statement in the streamwriter statement. I checked other forums, this is way is one of the acceptable ways for disposal. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can nullify the writer object after closing.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `writer.Flush();` before `writer.Close();`